# Countdown from specific date in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, countdown, calendarview

This is my code in which I open my Calendar dialog and choose a date and show it on the screen, now I need to make a countdown from the chosen date.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    CalendarView calendarView;
    TextView myDate, odbrojavanje;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        odbrojavanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odbrojavanje);
        Button dateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateBtn);

        dateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        String currentDateString = 
        DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(c.getTime());

        TextView dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateText);
        dateView.setText(currentDateString);
    }

}
```

I want my countdown in days to be shown in:

```
odbrojavanje = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.odbrojavanje);
```

Comment: What exactly is cuntdown? Are you trying to say countdown?

Comment: @Steven Yes countdown,  sorry.